# Ansible lookup file plugin with variable inside the file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Hei guys,

After a few days of struggling, I've decided to write my issue here.

I have an ansible(2.7) task that that has a single variable, which points to a host var that uses the file lookup plugin.

Thing is that this works, for one host, but I have 6 hosts, where a value inside the lookup file should be different for each of the hosts.

Can you pass a variable inside the file that is looked up?

I'm new to ansible and don't master it fully.

Has someone encountered this before?

```
Task:

- name: Copy the file to its directory
  template:
    src: file.conf
    dest: /path/to/file
  vars:
    file_contents: "{{file_configuration}}"

-----
hostvar file:

file_configuration: 
  - "{{lookup('file', './path/to/file') | from_yaml}}"

----
file that is looked up:

name: {{ value that should be different per host }}
    driver:
      long_name: unchanged value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have 6 `host_vars` files, one for each host. In that host_var file, set your desired value.

[Ansible documentation is here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#host-variables)

E.g.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZRq5.jpg

Content of host1.yml

```
---
my_value: something
```

Content of host2.yml

```
---
my_value: else
```

Ansible automagicly sees the `host_var` folder. It looks in that folder and searches for files which **exactly match** a host in the play. 
So ensure your host_var/**filename**.yml matches the hostname in your play!

If there is a match, then it'll use that .yml file for that specific host.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have 6 host var files and each host var file has this variable inside: file_configuration:   - "{{lookup('file', './path/to/file') | from_yaml}}". Ideea is that the file that is looked up, should have variable inside it, like an inception situation. We have a host var file variable that points to a file, and that file has another variable inside it.

Comment: This is because each file is looking to a single source.

In that single source, `'./path/to/file'`, you should specify variables for each host to use. Or create multiple `path/to/file1` and `path/to/file2`. Because else, there is no way to distinguish variables for your hosts.

Comment: Is there a way to enter a new line or variable in this line statement: file_configuration: 
  - "{{lookup('file', './path/to/file') | from_yaml}}"

Comment: Yes, you can use `with_items`